# How do I rebind the Glassfish Server reference for an Eclipse project on a new machine?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

So I've copied my Eclipse project over to a new machine. It has a reference in the .classpath file to a GlassFish server:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.runtimeTarget/GlassFish 3.1.2">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

I have now installed GlassFish 4.0 on the new machine, and GlassFish 3.1.2 on the old.

**Question 1**: Is there any way I can safely interchange developing on the old and new machine? Or must I have the same version of Glassfish on both?

**Question 2**: How do I rebind the server reference in the project? In project properties > build path, Eclipse reports "Unbound". I've configured the Server Runtime Environment under `Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime environments`. `GlassFish 4.0` is listed there. Yet it's not listed when I click Add `Library > Server Runtime` under `Project properties > Java Build path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've created your server runtime, right-click the project -> `Properties` -> `Project Facets` -> Select your server runtime from the `Runtime` tab.